# Exporting Multi-Valued Attributes in PowerShell to Excel - Attempting to Automate Using an Array of Hash Tables

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

I am trying to automate the unwrapping of multi-valued attributes in PowerShell for the purpose of exporting the information to an excel sheet. The known solution for enabling multi-valued exporting to excel is to manually create a hash table for each multi-valued attribute, which works just well. Example:

```
Get-ADForest -Server <servername> |

Select-Object @{Name='ApplicationPartitions';Expression={$.ApplicationPartitions}},
              DomainNamingMaster,
              @{Name="Domains";Expression={$.Domains}},
              ForestMode,
              @{Name="GlobalCatalogs";Expression={$.GlobalCatalogs}},
              Name,
              PartitionsContainer,
              RootDomain,
              SchemaMaster,
              @{Name="Sites";Expression={$.Sites}} |

Export-Csv $home'AD Forest Information.csv'
```

However, I would like to automate this for commands that have many multi-valued attributes. Here is what I have so far (I am using Get-ADForest for testing):

```
$Objects = @()

$Object = @{}

Get-ADForest | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.membertype -eq 'property'} |

Select-Object Name |

ForEach-Object {$Object = @{Name=$_.Name;Expression="$" + "_" + "." + $_.Name} ; $Objects +=$Object}

Write-Output $Objects

Get-ADForest -Server <servername> | Select-Object $Objects | Export-Csv $home\'AD Forest Information.csv'
```

The issue is that the exported .csv has the correct column titles, but the values of the attributes are still `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection` like they would be without unwrapping the attribute.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Any suggestions would be awesome.

Thank you!

Austin

Comment: I already provided a working solution to your problem on a post with the same name, what happened?

Comment: Hey Santisq, I deleted that question as I made several mistakes in it. This is the repost. This is my first time using stackoverflow, my apologies. Could you add the answer back to this question? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your example, let me know if this is what you expect as output for your csv:

```
cd $Home\Documents

function parseADObject{
param(
    [cmdletbinding()]
    [parameter(mandatory,valuefrompipeline)]
    $InputObject
)
    $properties=($inputObject|gm -MemberType Property).Name
    $parsedObject=@{}

    foreach($prop in $Properties)
    {
        $thisProp=$inputObject.$prop

        if($thisProp -and $thisProp.GetType() -match 'Collection|\[]')
        {
            $val=($inputObject.$prop|out-string).Trim()
        }
        elseif($thisProp -and $thisProp.GetType() -match 'Int|Boolean|Double')
        {
            $val=$thisProp
        }
        elseif($thisProp)
        {
            $val=($thisProp.ToString()).Trim()
        }
        else
        {
            $val=$null
        }

        $parsedObject.$prop=$val
    }

    return $parsedObject|%{New-Object PSObject -Property $_}
}

Get-ADForest|parseADObject|Export-Csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation;ii test.csv
```

Explanation, I'm gonna use ADForest for this example:

First you get the properties of the object you want to parse:

```
$adforest=Get-ADForest

PS C:\> $properties=($adforest|gm -MemberType Property).Name

PS C:\> $properties
ApplicationPartitions
CrossForestReferences
DomainNamingMaster
Domains
ForestMode
GlobalCatalogs
Name
PartitionsContainer
RootDomain
SchemaMaster
Sites
SPNSuffixes
UPNSuffixes
```

Then you loop on the properties of your object asking for the type of object:

```
PS C:\> foreach($prop in $properties){$adforest.$prop.gettype()}

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                         
True     False    ADPropertyValueCollection                System.Collections.CollectionBase                                
True     False    ADPropertyValueCollection                System.Collections.CollectionBase                                
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                    
True     False    ADPropertyValueCollection                System.Collections.CollectionBase                                
True     True     ADForestMode                             System.Enum                                                      
True     False    ADPropertyValueCollection                System.Collections.CollectionBase                                
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                    
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                    
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                    
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                    
True     False    ADPropertyValueCollection                System.Collections.CollectionBase                                
True     False    ADPropertyValueCollection                System.Collections.CollectionBase                                
True     False    ADPropertyValueCollection                System.Collections.CollectionBase
```

And then you're just asking what type of object it is:

- If the type matches `'Collection or []'` then you're passing the value of that property to `Out-String` this is useful for properties like `proxyAddresses` on the AD Users.
- ElseIf the type matches a `Boolean or Integer or Double` then you're leaving the value as is without any changes.
- ElseIf the the property has any Value, meaning, is not `$null`, I'm using the `ToString() method`. This is useful for properties like `ObjectGUID or ObjectSID`

Notice I'm using Trim() each time I use Out-String or ToString() to eliminate any empty blank spaces at the beginning or the end

The value of each property loop, stored in the `$val` variable is then being added to the hashTable `$parsedObject` and then after looping is finished the variable is being converted to a PSObject (if you don't do this the export will not show as you expect it, it will show the type of the values instead of the actual data).

Comment: This worked, thank you. How do I select this as a working solution? (:

If I may ask one other question, why does my method not work? Thank you very much for the solution!

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do with your script but I can explain what I'm with mine. I'll edit my post explaining it in a few.

Comment: Wow, your explanation is great! Thank you very much santisq. Any chance you could go into more detail on why you have to convert the hashtable to a psobject? Greatly appreciate your time.

Comment: you can try that yoursef, replace the `return $parsedObject|%{New-Object PSObject -Property $_}` for `return $parsedObject` and export to csv like that and see what happens.

Comment: ahh, thank you again! what I was trying to do is create a string that contained the syntax for the 'Select-Object' command. I realize in my post that I was putting it into an array, which I have since changed to a string, but even still it does not work. The string looks correct (it contains all of the formatting for the manual method), but when put into the 'Select-Object' command, it takes it all as a single string. I am not sure of a way to get this method to work, likely I am just going at it the wrong way. let me know what you think (:

Comment: this is a partial snip of what the string contains (when using the Get-ADForest command for testing) : 

@{Name=ApplicationPartitions;Expression={$_.ApplicationPartitions}},@{Name=CrossForestReferences;Expression={$_.CrossForestReferences}},@{Name=DomainNamingMaster;Expression={$_.DomainNamingMaster}},@{Name=Do
mains;Expression={$_.Domains}},@{Name=ForestMode;Expression={$_.ForestMode}},@{Name=GlobalCatalogs;Expression={$_.GlobalCatalogs}},@{Name=Name;Expression={$_.Name}},@{Name=PartitionsContainer;Expression={$_.
PartitionsContainer}},@{Name=RootDomain;Expression={$_.RootDomain}}